# 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

I'm trying to iterate an array (in form of constant) of tuples:

```
SPRITE_RIGHT = [(0, 0), (16, 0), (32, 0)]
SPRITE_LEFT = [(0, 16), (16, 16), (32, 0)]
SPRITE_UP = [(0, 32), (16, 32), (32, 0)]
SPRITE_DOWN = [(0, 48), (16, 48), (32, 0)]
def symbol(self):
    self._status += 1

    if (self._status > 2):
        self._status = 0

    if (self._dx > 0):
        (x, y) = PacMan.SPRITE_RIGHT[self._status]
        return (x,y)
    if (self._dx < 0):
        (x, y) = PacMan.SPRITE_LEFT[self._status]
        return (x,y)
    if (self._dy > 0):
        (x, y) = PacMan.SPRITE_DOWN[self._status]
        return (x,y)
    if (self._dy < 0):
        (x, y) = PacMan.SPRITE_UP[self._status]
        return (x,y)
...
for a in arena.actors():
        if not isinstance(a, Wall):
            x, y, w, h = a.rect()
            xs, ys = a.symbol()                #This line gives me the problem
            screen.blit(sprites, (x, y), area=(xs, ys, w, h))
```

When I execute the program I receive this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

For every actor I call the method symbol() to get its image

> When i print PacMan.SPRITE_UP[0] for example it returns the correct
>   tuple

Comment: The code you posted seems correct, assuming a reasonable value for `self._status`. Maybe you omitted a bit too much. Can you try to make a minimal working example that still shows the error when executed?

Comment: So SPRITE_RIGHT[self._status] is None

Comment: That's a minimal example reproducing the Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value returned by `a.symbol()`. It looks like it's trying to unreel it into two values and failing.

When you do this:

```
xs, ys = a.symbol()     #This line gives me the problem
```

it calls `a.symbol()`, which returns a value. The code assumes that this
value is an iterable containing two values. `xs` and `ys` are then
changed to references to those two values.

If the value returned by `a.symbol()` is anything other than such an
iterable, the assignment will fail. The error message you got,
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, suggests that
`a.symbol()` is returning `None`.

Comment: When i print PacMan.SPRITE_UP[0] for example it returns the correct tuple

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. I didn't consider a particular value of dx